# Need to set class/id values on buttons in Extjs MessageBox

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Our testing team require IDs or class values to be set on the HTML elements in our **message popup boxes**. This is for their automated tests.

I can pass in a class value for the dialog panel by passing in a **cls** value like so:

> ```
>                 Ext.Msg.show({
>                     title:'Reset Grid Layout',
>                     msg: 'Are you sure that you want to reset the grid layout?',
>                     cls:'Reset-Grid-Layout-Message',
>                     buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
>                     fn: function (response) {
>                         if (response == 'yes') {
>                         }
>                     },
>                     icon: Ext.window.MessageBox.QUESTION
>                 });
> ```

Now we also need it on the buttons, and also on the text being displayed. Is there some way of getting a **cls** value onto the buttons?

I was thinking it may be possible to expand the button parameter into something like :

```
buttons : [{name:'but1', cls:'asdf'}, {name:'but2', cls:'asdf2'}]
```

But google is not giving me back anything useful.

Comment: check this http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.button.Button.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your testing team uses Selenium for their automated test, adding ids/classes in every component could be difficult for both of you.

Overriding components in Ext is a good solution, but I don't recommend this because it will affect all your components. Unless you know what you're doing.

I suggest, extend `Ext.window.MessageBox` and generate classes for your buttons based on your parent cls.

```
// Put this somewhere like /custom/messagebox.js
Ext.define('App.MyMessageBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.MessageBox'
    ,initConfig: function(config) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
    ,makeButton: function(btnIdx) {
        var me = this;               
        var btnId = me.buttonIds[btnIdx];

        return new Ext.button.Button({
            handler: me.btnCallback
            ,cls: me.cls + '-' + btnId
            ,itemId: btnId
            ,scope: me
            ,text: me.buttonText[btnId]
            ,minWidth: 75
        });
    }
});
```

To use:

```
App.Box = new App.MyMessageBox({
    cls:'reset-grid-layout'
}).show({
    title:'Reset Grid Layout'
    ,msg: 'Are you sure that you want to reset the grid layout?'
    ,buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO
    ,icon: Ext.window.MessageBox.QUESTION    
});
```

Your buttons will have `reset-grid-layout-yes` and `reset-grid-layout-no` class.

You can do the same with other components you have. Check out the Fiddle. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7qb

Comment: thanks perfect! I will give you bounty in a few hours when SO allows me.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-cls)

> cls : String A CSS class string to apply to the button's main element.
>
> Overrides: Ext.AbstractComponent.cls

You can also use the filter on right side (not the one in the right top corner). Just type `cls` and you will see all properties, methods and events containing `cls` (note that you see by default just public members, use the menu on  the right of this searchfield to extend this)

**Edit**

If you just need it for testing purpose I would recommend to override the responsible method. This should work (untested!)

```
Ext.window.MessageBox.override({
    buttonClasses: [
        'okCls', 'yesCls', 'noCls', 'cancelCls'
    ],

    makeButton: function(btnIdx) {
        var btnId = this.buttonIds[btnIdx];
        var btnCls = this.buttonClasses[btnIdx];
        return new Ext.button.Button({
            handler: this.btnCallback,
            cls: btnCls,
            itemId: btnId,
            scope: this,
            text: this.buttonText[btnId],
            minWidth: 75
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I am trying to get a handle on the buttons in the message box. ie. buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO. Once I have them i know i can set cls and other things

Comment: @OliverWatkins Ok. See my edit. It's a bit tricky because the buttons are created within the singleton and don't apply a config property. There may be other ways by query the buttons and set the cls for each one but I recommend a override here.

Comment: seems to be right direction. But you have Ext.window.MessageBox and I have Ext.Msg. Not sure what difference. Ext.window.MessageBox has no show() method.

Comment: confused over differences between Ext.Msg, Ext.MessageBox, and Ext.window.MessageBox :(

Comment: bounty is yours if you can give me a runnable example :)

Comment: @OliverWatkins  maybee tomorrow